# How can I make a dropdown menu to be open by default?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm making my application using Bootstrap and Laravel 7, I have a dropdown menu in my dashboard and I would like it to be open by default all the time. How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Code in my Blade View:

```
<li class="side-menus nav-item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link has-dropdown"><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
        <span>Job Cards</span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu side-menus">
            <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/new-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.new-jobcard.index') }}">
                    <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>New</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/potential-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.potential-jobcard.index') }}">
                        <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Potential</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/progress-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.progress-jobcard.index') }}">
                        <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>In Progress</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="side-menus {{ Request::is('client/complete-jobcard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('client.complete-jobcard.index') }}">
                        <i class="far fa-address-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Completed</span>
                    </a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery, you can also use native javascript though.

In this instance we use jQuery for code purposes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".your-dropdown-btn").click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm not so familiar with jQuery, how can I achieve this with native JavaScript?

Comment: try to use this

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('ID_SELECTOR').click();
}

Comment: I was able to fix with CSS, I have added `display: inline-block;` in my CSS file.